# how to write test cases using iframe in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

My html code is

```
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;"><span id="cke_28" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span><iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor-full" aria-describedby="cke_28" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe></div>
<span id="cke_28" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>**
**<iframe src="" frameborder="0" class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, editor-full" aria-describedby="cke_28" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

my scripts look like
select frame=//*[@id="cke_1_contents"]

Answer (score 0):

Typically you should call the [Select Frame](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame) keyword, giving it a locator for the frame. In your case it might look something like this:

```
Select frame   //iframe[@id="cke_1_contents"]
```